Is there a way to know if my mouse pointer changed to a custom one
I'm trying to make a tool for a game which they use custom images for their mouse pointer. Is there anyway to actually detect that the pointer changed from that image to that image or from the normal Windows pointer to a custom one?

You need to capture WM_SETCURSOR messages.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
